# Slide Image horizontally on Hover using css3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have tried to make the horizontal slider, that will slide image on hover of a div. But it didn't work.

How should I modify the code for that?

Here is the link for that http://www.kirupa.com/html5/slide_image_hover_using_css3.htm

Comment: use `left` instead of `top` wherever it appears on the code (even on transition). Then show your attempts in fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Follow this simple steps to create this animation

- Just take one container and apply height and width and also overflow hidden.
- Put one image having two square exact  same width as container.
- then on hover of the dive move image upwards `top: -150px;`
- and for animation add `transition: top 1s ease-in-out;`

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.smiley {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.container:hover .smiley {
  top: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/fy1v2e.png" class="smiley">
</div>
```

### And here is the full version of that slider

```css
.slider {
  width: 325px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.container {
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
.smiley {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.container:hover .smiley {
  top: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/fy1v2e.png" class="smiley">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/15d9isj.png" class="smiley">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2uha93k.png" class="smiley">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/2dgnj84.png" class="smiley">
  </div>
</div>
```

### cheers